# Como configurar o componente JUnit do Demoiselle 2.4.2 para injetar dependências EJB

Tags: java, demoiselle

Tenho uma aplicação Demoiselle 2.4.2/JSF/Hibernate que apresenta vários casos de teste em pleno funcionamento. Os BCs operados por estes casos de teste sofrem diversas injeções de dependência sem problema algum. Agora precisei da injeção de um cliente EJB, como mostrado no código abaixo:

```
@BusinessController
public class MeuBC implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private SecurityServices securityServices;
    @Inject
    private TipoVinculoBC tipoVinculoBC;

    @EJB(lookup=Constantes.EXTERNAL_SERVICE_JNDI)
    private ExternalService EXTERNALService; // <=== Preciso desta injeção!!!

    // Restante da classe
}
```

No exemplo, temos `TipoVinculoBC` sendo injetado sem problema. No entanto, **durante os testes apenas** (funciona na execução da aplicação) `ExternalService` não é injetado, permanecendo com o valor `null` durante a execução, resultando em erro.

Ressalto que **não se trata de teste de integração**, `ExternalService` **não está em teste**, é apenas um serviço do qual o código de `MeuBC` depende (como qualquer outra API), logo é um teste unitário de `MeuBC`.

O que está faltando para que o `DemoiselleRunner` ou outro participante possa viabilizar a injeção do cliente de `ExternalService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex, o CDI, que é quem faz a injeção de depedências `@Inject`, inclusive no teste unitário, [não dá suporte a anotações específicas do EJB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8138452/504921).

A sugestão é você [criar um `Producer` que obtém seu objeto do contexto do EJB para poder utilizar `@Inject`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28232648/504921) nas classes que precisam dessa dependência.

Note que isto não é uma limitação do `DemoiselleRunner`, mas do CDI em si.